# Help with comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the sum [image]

I need to use the comparison test since ratio test and root test are inconclusive (equals 1). But I can't find a suitable Sum to compare to this one. Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: Rationalising the numerator could be a good move.

Comment: Try multiplying by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n \over\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n $ first.

Comment: Ok I got this : 1 / (n*sqrt(n) + n*sqrt(n+1)) ,  how do I proceed?

Comment: Note$$0\le{1\over n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\,)}\le{1\over n(\sqrt{n }+\sqrt n\,)}=   {1\over 2n^{3/2}}.$$ Now think about $p$-series.

Comment: OK, got it done. Thank you very much for the help.